# :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

Jenkins returns me the following error when I run the `gradlew assembleDebug`.
In Android Studio 3.0 I don't have this problem.
Does anyone know the reason?

```
AAPT err(Facade for 2147483181): \\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\e9979393938d5eeff956c6f4b76be0a3\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: 

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at
```

What I tryied

gradle.properties

```
android.enableAapt2=false
android.enableBuildCache=true#and false
android.buildCacheDir=c:/temp/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you apply these operations separately?

- Check the path to your project. If the path is too long, then move up your project to an upper directory.
- If Path contains non-ASCII characters, correct it.
- Clear the build cache. See [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html) for details.

On Windows:

`gradlew cleanBuildCache`

On Mac or Linux:

`./gradlew cleanBuildCache`

- > Go to gradle.properties file, and disable build cache.
  >
  > // To re-enable
  >   the build cache, either delete the following
  >
  > // line or set the
  >   property to 'true'.
  >
  > android.enableBuildCache=false the other way is to
  >   modify build cache dir by adding first line can be skipped because
  >   true is the default value by 2.3
  >
  > `android.enableBuildCache=true`
  >
  > `android.buildCacheDir =c:\temp\`
- Invalidate Caches / Restart then Clean and Rebuild project